# NullPointerException with Java Filescanner

Tags: java

Trying to make a simple console based address book. The first method is my "load" method, which gets the data from a text file. However, it throws an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pack.AddressBook.load(AddressBook.java:18)
    at pack.AddressBook.main(AddressBook.java:33)
```

My AddressBook Class looks like this:

```
public class AddressBook {

public static Student [] load() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which file do you want to access?");
    String filename = input.nextLine();
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    Student [] studentArray = new Student[1];
    int i = 0;
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        studentArray[i].firstName = fileScanner.nextLine();
        studentArray[i].lastName = fileScanner.nextLine();
        studentArray[i].age = fileScanner.nextLine();
        studentArray[i].grade = fileScanner.nextLine();
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return null;
    input.close();
    fileScanner.close();
    return studentArray;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws entryError, FileNotFoundException {
    Student [] studentsInCurrentBook = load();
}


}
```

My Student Class looks like this (if it matters):

```
public class Student {
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String age;
public String grade;

public Student() throws entryError{
    throw new entryError("Please provide at least a first and last name.");
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    age = "unknown";
    grade = "unknown";
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String age){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    grade = "unknown";
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String grade, char i){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    age = "unknown";
    this.grade = grade;
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String age, String grade){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.grade = grade;
}

}
```

And the students.txt file is formatted like this:

```
firstname
lastname
age
grade
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are returning null right after your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't add any student in the `studentArray` You only create an array of `Student` objects and then try to access the `Student` at index `i` which of course is empty. What you need to do is add `studentArray[i] = new Student();` and then the `while` loop or just do this:

```
studentArray[i] = new Student(fileScanner.nextLine(), fileScanner.nextLine(), fileScanner.nextLine(), fileScanner.nextLine());
```

or this:

```
String firstName, lastName, age, grade;

while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    firstName = fileScanner.nextLine();
    lastName = fileScanner.nextLine();
    age = fileScanner.nextLine();
    grade = fileScanner.nextLine();
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}


studentArray[i] = new Student(firstName, lastName, age, grade);
```

etc... Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
Student [] studentArray = new Student[1];
int i = 0;
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    studentArray[i].firstName = fileScanner.nextLine();
    studentArray[i].lastName = fileScanner.nextLine();
    studentArray[i].age = fileScanner.nextLine();
    studentArray[i].grade = fileScanner.nextLine();
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

So you create an empty array with size one, and then you attempt to set fields in its `i`th element.
You need to create a Student to go in your array before you can start accessing studentArray[i] fields. Until you do, `null` is the only thing in your array, which is why you get a `NullPointerException`.

And then you need to make sure your array has enough length to hold all the students you add (so you are probably better off using an ArrayList).